# How to await MailMessage.SendAsync?

Tags: c#, asynchronous

If I do this:

```
public async Task<SendEmailServiceResponse> ExecuteAsync(SendEmailServiceRequest request)
    {
        ....
        var response = new SendEmailServiceResponse();
        await client.SendAsync(mail, null); // Has await
        response.success = true;
        return response;
    }
```

Then I get this:

> Cannot await 'void'

But if I do this:

```
public async Task<SendEmailServiceResponse> ExecuteAsync(SendEmailServiceRequest request)
    {
        ....
        var response = new SendEmailServiceResponse();
        client.SendAsync(mail, null); // No Await
        response.success = true;
        return response;
    }
```

I get this:

> The async method lacks 'await' and will run synchronously.

I'm clearly missing something, just not sure what.

Comment: Despite its name, SendAsync is not async method (in terms of async\await), because it does not return Task.

Comment: Short answer.. you don't. It's a syncronous method in the context of the api.

Comment: So.... it's not possible to send an email async?

Comment: `SendMailAsync()` returns a Task, if you can use this method instead you can `await` it.  There are two overloads, check the [docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.smtpclient(v=vs.110).aspx#Methods) for details

Comment: A better question would be - why do you need to (await it)?

Comment: thanks @maccettura!! Not yet tested, but it looks like it will work. Off to give it a try!

Comment: Well SendAsync is asynchronous - it won't block and result is delivered later via SendCompleted. It just does not conform to Task based async api. So as suggested above - use SendMailAsync instead.

Comment: @Mardoxx -- why does anyone use async?

Comment: Just because you're not relying on `await` magic doesn't mean it's gonna block your thread

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As others have pointed out `SendAsync` is a bit misleading.  It returns a `void`, not a `Task`.  If you want to `await` a send mail call you need to use the method

```
SendMailAsync(MailMessage message)
```

or

```
SendMailAsync(string from, string recipients, string subject, string body)
```

Both of these return a `Task` and can be awaited

Comment: This is not the correct answer at all! `The async method lacks 'await' and will run synchronously.` means the method does not have any await call yet is marked as "async", not a problem with the call to SendAsync.

Comment: My answer is just as valid as removing the `async` keyword from the OP's `ExecuteAsync()` method.  I inferred from the OP's post that they wanted to use async/await patterns so I gave the OP a solution that utilized the async/await pattern.

Comment: That does not mean that the call to SendAsync is wrong because of not using the await keyword, which is what the OP suggests.

Comment: The OP's question is literally **"How to await MailMessage.SendAsync?"**.  Since it is impossible to await `SendAsync()` I suggested the OP use the method `SendMailAsync()` which was added in 4.5 so that it specifically could be awaited.  In no place have I suggested that using `SendAsync()` is wrong, just that it cannot be awaited (again the OP's question specifically asks how to **await**)